# Could not find any version that matches org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3.+

Tags: android, maven, gradle, robolectric

When syncing my Gradle project in Android Studio, I get the following error:

> Error:Could not find any version that matches org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3.+.
>   Required by:
>       gradle:android:unspecified

I assume I am missing a repository in my build.gradle file. I'm new to Gradle and Maven, so I'm not sure what I should put. Any suggestions?

Here are my build.gradle files:

Project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.2.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Module:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bbct.android.common"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
            versionCode 14
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
    }
    def Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

        if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
                props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
            android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
            android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
        } else {
            println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
            android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
        }
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties not found'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    liteCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3.+'
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you drop the plus sign? The "Gradle, please" site gives me an option without it. I know this sound weird, but who knows.

Comment: @DavidCesarino What's the "Gradle, please" site?

Comment: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ - It's a site that helps figuring out the proper lines for Maven Central in Gradle. Again, I know it does not make (much) sense to drop the plus sign, but IIRC this has happened to me in the past.

Comment: Sweet, that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, try dropping the plus sign. Technically, it shouldn't make a difference (hence why I was hesitant to post it as an answer), but as I stated, I'm pretty sure this has happened to me in the past.

I'm glad it solved your problem. :)