# gradle version not found

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

My app was running fine, I rebooted my pc, tried to run it, and i get the following error message

```
Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
Search in build.gradle
```

I'm running android studio 0.80 on Ubuntu 14.04

[Answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708230/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-org-robolectricrobolectric2-3)  suggest that removing the sign plus could solve the problem, I removed it but the problem remaind

my gradle.build files

module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dnsoftware.mutesmart"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'

}
```

project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `0.12.2` instead of `0.12.+`. There is no `0.12` version, if that's what you tried.

Comment: yes there is a difference, the version number in the error message changed.

Comment: Did you try with `0.12.2`?